# Removing characters from URL (php)

Tags: php, url

My site (rillist.com) uses php to grab facebook URLS.
I've noticed many users accidentally paste in extra characters (?fref=ts) to the id, because they're just copy/pasting.

Is there a way to force certain phrases out of what the php echos?
Thank you

Comment: so you're trying to get rid of everything after the `?` in your URLs?

Comment: strpos substr.. have you tried them?

Comment: to be honest I paid someone to write most of the code because I don't know to try these types of things. Thanks for your patience

Answer (score 2):

I have built these two functions for similar issues in my scripts.
They might be what you need for your trouble.

P.S. Please try to be more specific and add some examples of codes URL's etc to help ppl understand better what you want to do.

```
  # Removing param from QUERY_STRING.
  function unkey_querystring($query_string, $key) { 
    $query_array = array();
    parse_str($query_string, $query_array);

    unset($query_array[$key]);

    $query_string = http_build_query($query_array);

    return $query_string;
  }

  # Remove param from URL.
  function unkey_address($url, $key) { 
    $query_string = substr(strstr($url, "?"), 1);
    $base_url = str_replace($query_string, "", $url);

    $query_string = unkey_querystring($query_string, $key);
    return $base_url.$query_string; 
  }
```

Comment: another issue is that my urls look like this:
http://rillist.com/?id=el.tee
and the undesirable url looks like this:
http://rillist.com/?id=el.tee?fref=ts

Comment: you mean rillist.com/?id=el.tee&fref=ts with a few string functions you can solve all your trouble. http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using regular expressions:

```
$bad_url = "rillist.com/?id=el.tee?fref=ts";
$good_url = preg_replace('/(.+\?[^?]+)\?.*/sim', '$1', $bad_url);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a rather elegant way to do this, **but** it requires the [pecl_http](http://pecl.php.net/package/pecl_http) extension.

```
http_build_url($url, array(), HTTP_URL_STRIP_QUERY)
```

A PHP port of `http_build_url` can be found [here](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/wp-minify/trunk/http_build_url.php), and you should be able to drop it into any codebase without issue... I used this code to verify my solution.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you want to do *something* like this:

```
$url = 'http://facebook.com/page?test=yes&fref=ts'; // the facebook URL

$_MGET = parse_url($url); // split the URL into path, query and host

$_MGET = '?'.$_MGET['query']; // re-set $_MGET with a better query

if(strpos($_MGET, "fref=ts") > 0) { // find out if their is "fref=ts"
  $before_fref = $_MGET[strpos($_MGET, "fref=ts")-1]; // get character before "fref=ts"
  $_MGET = str_replace(($before_fref == "?" ? "fref=ts&" : "&fref=ts"), "", $_MGET); // replace "fref=ts" according to previous char
}

echo $_MGET; // echo new url

// unset
unset($_MGET);
unset($before_fref);
```

(this works as-is, sorry for the bad variable names)